# A simple C library filling the gaps in standard (C, POSIX) libraries?

Tags: c, libraries

I'm looking for a C function library, which would contain a collection of *simple and plain* utility functions "missing" from C or POSIX standards. I found [this earlier question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/116650/is-there-any-boost-equivalent-library-for-c), but answers there list only full frameworks or libraries designed to replace/duplicate standard libraries instead of seamlessly fill the gaps.

To give you an example of functions I'm often missing, and would like to find a lib with tested implementations:

- `afgets`, `afread`: read a line or entire file, like `fgets` and `fread`, except really reads all and returns a `malloc`ed buffer, in the spirit of GNU `asprintf`.
- A selection of string trimming functions
- `systemf`, `popenf`: Like `system` and `popen`, but take `printf`-like format string for command.
- `strjoin`: join multiple strings given as vararg/array (which is hard to do with `snprintf`)
- `struct timeval` arithmetic

These are just examples of functions I often miss for quick stuff. Then some features I'd desire (not mandatory):

- Available on common Linux distros out-of-the-box, with man pages etc
- Works also on Windows/Visual C
- No extra dependencies, self-contained
- As usable as existing C lib functions in C++
- Preferably licensed under LGPL or BSD-like license, but GPL is ok too

Stuff which I am *not* looking for:

- A string library with its own string type
- A data structure library
- A framework library which has special initialization, maybe even event loop etc.

So the question is, what is out there? Library name, homepage link, github link, duplicate question link... If you've made your own and have it at public repo, feel free to link to that too, if you dare expose it to many eyes.

Comment: Commenting on downvote/close: I thought *Programmers* was just the place for a question like this. The need for such a library is very real (first list of my bullets). Please leave feedback on how to improve the question, or comment why it's unsalvageable.

Comment: I know one that is open source and in the early stages of active development. Currently a specification has been published: [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/193733/1033). Contributors are welcome.

Comment: @mouviciel :'D  (assuming that was intentional and not a copy-paste error)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any Boost equivalent library for C?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/116650/is-there-any-boost-equivalent-library-for-c)

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau While the APR answer there may be the closest thing available, I think that question wants some functionality and features provided by boost. At least the answers there answer it from this point of view, not "augments standard library without replacing it" point of view.

Comment: @hyde: If you had asked this question in the context of C++, Boost would have been one of the very first suggestions. That is my basis for marking it as a duplicate. Given that your criteria are quite specific, it is unlikely that there is a publicly available library that meets them.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Then interesting (to me) question is why, because I bet most C programmers have written the same small utility functions over and over again, or worse written same code snippets inline over and over again, or maybe even worse just ignored corner cases (like lines longer than fixed buffer they pass to `fgets`) to keep code simpler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Apache Portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org/) has a lot of what you want.

Do not expect anything to come from either C or POSIX. The C/C++ standards group think you should be using C++ and C is only for legacy apps. POSIX is run by a group of hardware manufacturers who will fight any change to the standard as they would incur the expense of implementing any change in their various OSes.

There are lots of functions not easily found on thier web site e.g. [apr_file_read_full](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__file__io.html#gaf39a17404e868808aff8e2e7ecaa87e0)

Comment: At a quick glance APR (which is one answer in the linked question) looked like standard library replacement, but at a closer look it might be acceptable, +1. For example string funcs: http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__strings.html

Comment: ...though I did not (yet) find a function to read a line of arbitrary length from a file, or entire file, which is a bit of a bummer.

Comment: About `apr_file_read_full`, yeah I noticed that, with high hopes... But it does not read full file, it reads full buffer, blocking. I'm not actually sure what is the use case so common, that it warrants adding a special function to public API.

Comment: I don't think the OP was looking for changes to the C or POSIX standards.

Comment: @hyde -- just allocate a buffer big enough for the file, and, slurp it in with apr_file_read_full. Not quite the whole thing but doable with only three function calls.

Comment: lol. C is only for legacy apps??!?!  Some of the greatest apps used today have been written relatively recently are heavily used today.

Comment: @Man Vs Code -- totally agree C is far more relevent than C++, but the standards process has been hi-jacked by C++ proponents.